# Is it standard practice to keep a FIX connection connected all day long, or relogin periodically?

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I wrote a program in Python using the quickfix package which connects to a vendor via FIX. We login in the morning, but don't actually send messages through the connection until the end of the day. The issue is, we don't want to keep the program open for the entirety of the day, but would rather relogin in the afternoon when we need to send the messages.

The vendor is requesting we stay logged in for the full duration between our start and stop times specified in our configurations. This is only possible by leaving my program on for the entirety of the day, because if I close it then the messages the vendor sends aren't registered as received by me. I don't send a logout message though.

Is it common practice to write a program to connect via FIX and leave it running for the entire session time? Or is it acceptable to close the program, given I don't send a logout message, and reconnect at a later time in the day?

Any design or best practice advice would be helpful here.

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with this sector, but here is a quote ["_Disconnection without the exchange of Logout <5> messages should be interpreted as an abnormal condition._"](https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.2/msgType_5_5.html). Not sure how correct this is.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is: if your vendor wants you to stay connected for the full duration, what is the problem with that? That is, why is "leaving my program on for the entirety of the day" difficult?  Your computer is filled with programs that are *always running*; this isn't an especially unusual situation.

Comment: On further reading there seems to be a heartbeat, therefore I suspect that if you disconnect without logging out, you will miss the heartbeat messages and the provider will terminate your session, therefore forcing you to relogin later on.

Comment: I think there are two sides to consider (non-FIX specific). **A)** Should you leave the program running if your client/vendor has asked you to do so: **Probably Yes** - if they asked, it's likely because they have a good reason for asking you to. **B)** Should you expect the connection to be stable all day? **No** - Connections of any kind are not to be fully 'trusted' for long term stability - expect that it might fail and write your application to handle that/automatically reconnect when needed (if possible).

Comment: @PacoH. This is correct. The heartbeats will be missed and then restart once I restart the program.

Comment: @Bilkokuya and larsks, the only reason I don't want to leave it on all day is that Python GUI's are notorious for freezing. So I anticipate situations of leaving the program running all day long where it would have to be restarted occasionally. I wanted to avoid that but I'll look into solving the Python GUI problem based on your advice.

Comment: @Alex F Consider accepting an answer if you feel one is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it common practice to write a program to connect via FIX and leave it running for the entire session time? Or is it acceptable to close the program, given I don't send a logout message, and reconnect at a later time in the day?

I don't know what others have done, but I used QuickFIX with Python for years and never had any problem running my system all day, OR shutting it down periodically for whatever reason and reconnecting. In the end I wound up leaving the system connected for weeks at a time, since that allowed me to record data.

I would say that the answer to both of your questions is YES. It is common to leave it running. Also, it is acceptable to just close the program.

There can always be edge cases and idiosyncratic features of your implementation and your counterparty, so you should seek to understand more why they have asked you not to disconnect. That sounds very strange to me. Is their FIX engine not capable of something very simple and standard?

Comment: I think the reason the vendor asks you to remain logged in all day is the way they're monitoring connections / disco's means that anything outside scheduled connectivity times is considered an error that may need to be investigated and fixed. That sounds somewhat too strict...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is common to keep the FIX sessions running for a long time. That should not be an issue.

You can't just shutdown your program your end, as Session-level [FIX.Heartbeat(35=0)](http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.0/msgType_0_0.html) messages, sent periodically (usually 30s), as meant to keep the underlying TCP connection "open", and check that both ends are still up and running properly.

By the details you gave, if your vendor (which is likely the acceptor side) requests it, it might be because they need to send you messages, with no delay as they occur. 
If you (the initiator side) are not logged in at that time, they won't be able to send those messages, as they won't be able to initiate a session with you.

The vendor might monitor sessions as well, but as an initiator, it sounds odd.
as initiators are waiting for connections.
More likely they will monitor unexpected sessions drops.

All in all, it very depends of your vendor anyway, you have to follow what they say...